# Anchor `declare_id!` with Environment Variable - Environment Variables in Macros

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

In anchor the "top" of any program features a `declare_id!()` statement. The input to that statement is a `Pubkey`, typically in the form of a hard coded string. 12Factor Methodology typically dictates that hard coded configuration values like this should be avoided. However trying to not hard code the value has me pulling out my hair.

```
declare_id!(std::env::var("VARIABLE_NAME"));
```

Does not work because the `env::var` call executes at runtime while the macro executes at compile time.

```
declare_id!(env!("VARIABLE_NAME"));
```

Does not work because `env!` returns a `&str`.

```
declare_id!(Pubkey::from_str(env!("VARIABLE_NAME")));
```

Does not work because `Pubkey::from_str` can fail and as such returns a `Result`

```
declare_id!(Pubkey::from_str(env!("VARIABLE_NAME")).unwrap());
```

Does not work because `declare_id!` requires a constant and constants cannot be made from `unwrap` (Its probably more nuanced than that, but I'm new to rust) and `?` fails for the same reason.

1. How would I go about defining an environment variable within a macro?
2. Given the lack of resources on the topic, I'm presuming an environment variable in this case is **not** a best practice. Why should one **not** use an environment variable in this case?
3. How can one accomplish the injection of program id into an anchor application if environment variables are not the way to do so?

---

Bonus points:

`env::var()` returns a `Result<&str>`

`env::var_os()` returns a `Result<&OsStr>`

`env!()` returns a `&str`

`env_os!()` does not exist in `core`

How do you handle an `OsStr` environment variable at build time? Why would you not need to be able to?

Comment: The documentation of `declare_id!()` specifies that its argument has to be a string literal. You can't create a string literal through some function call, it literally has to be a written out string. That's at least my impression after 2 minutes of research, so take it with a grain of salt :)

Comment: It's weird that the docs say this, because the implementation seems to accept arbitrary expressions :/

Comment: In common use I have seen it take a string literal. Passing a variable in instead expects a Pubkey. I'm betting its overloads doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with env vars seems troublesome, since most of the ways of creating a `Pubkey` aren't `const fn`. To me, this seems like an issue with the `anchor-lang` crate, usually env vars aren't this troublesome.

That said, you could write the key to a config file somewhere, and read that in using `include_bytes`, and pass that to `Pubkey::new_from_array`, which *is* const:

```rust
// this works because concat! expands to a string literal
const BYTES: &[u8; 32] = include_bytes!(concat!(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"), "/key"));
anchor_lang::declare_id!(Pubkey::new_from_array(*BYTES));
```

If you don't want to store the file in the repo, you can point `include_bytes!()` at any location, even one read from an env var. For example, you could have:

```rust
const BYTES: &[u8; 32] = include_bytes!(env!("ANCHOR_KEY_LOCATION"));
anchor_lang::declare_id!(Pubkey::new_from_array(*BYTES));
```

which will read the key bytes from a file at `$ANCHOR_KEY_LOCATION`

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a crate [`const_str_to_pubkey`](https://crates.io/crates/const_str_to_pubkey) to address this issue. The crate provides a `const fn` that converts a `&'static str` to a `Pubkey`. You can do the following:

```rust
const MY_PUBKEY: Pubkey = str_to_pubkey(env!("VARIABLE_NAME"));
```